# Wordpress/Woocommerce Product Page Slug Incorrect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm struggling with this one issue for a while now, after hours of googling and tinkering i can't seem to find the issue.

My woocommerce pagination (next, prev) buttons append the url to /page/2. However, I need them to append /?product-page=2 instead, as that brings up the page correctly. I am trying to set up an Ajax "load more" button which uses /?product-page=2, hence why I believe it's correct.

Any help or pointers on this would be amazing, I'm not sure where else to turn at this point.

Cheers
Dan

Comment: Why can't you append `/page/{incrementalPageNumber}` ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Also my ajax button goes from page 1 to 2 and back to 1 again, so not sure on that either :/

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to **load more posts with ajax** on Wordpress, is to **display the list of posts** with a **next page button** that I create like this :

```
<?php global $wp_query;?>

<?php $next_link = get_next_posts_link( 'Load more' , $wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php if($next_link) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $next_link; ?>" id="#loadMore">
<?php endif; ?>
```

So my **html page after php render** looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Head stuff -->
</head>
<body>
   <h1>List of posts</h1>
   <ul id="postsList">
        <li>Post 1</li>
        ....
        </li>Post 10</li>
   </ul>
    <a href="http://example.com/posts-list/page/2" id="#loadMore">
</body>
</html>
```

If I click on the the load i will of course **reload the page** and then the load more post link will be `http://example.com/posts-list/page/3`

Now if I want the posts to be load with ajax and the load more button to be updated with the next page href IF there is a next page I do this in javascript:

```
$('#loadMore').on('click', function(e){

  // Prevent the link reload the page
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(response){
      // Get the next page html and convert it to jquery elemnt
      let nextPageHTML = $(response);

      // Get the next page posts list
      let nextPagePostsList = nextPageHTML.find('#postsList').html();

      // Get the next page load more button
      let nextPageLoadMore = nextPageHTML.find('#loadMore');

      // Append the next page posts
      $('#postsList').append(nextPagePostsList);

      // If there is a load more link on the next page update the current load more href
      if(nextPageLoadMore.length) {
          $('#loadMore').attr('href', nextPageLoadMore.attr('href'));    
      }
    }
});
```

I hope this was clear. I hadn't tested the code so tell me if something is not working.

---

Resume:

You need to have:

- An ID on your posts lists
- An ID on your load more link
- A next page button created with the wordpress function
- To add an ajax logic to get next page posts

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the detailed response. Sorry, i'm not sure where I should be putting this code? I guessed the javascript can go on my page in script tags. How about the other code? Sorry i'm a bit confused.

Comment: The javascript between script tags and the first code snippet should be on the page you want the load more to display.

Comment: So i've pasted the code as you said, into a wordpress page, with the javascript between script tags just below it, but sadly this doesn't work. Part of the code is being printed on the page (global $wp_query;). I am probably being stupid here but could you advise? Thanks D

Comment: Sorry, for the part with wp query it has to be between php tags : `<?php global $wp_query; ?>` and put the script just before then body end tag `</body>`

Comment: Hi, so the only issue now is 'max_num_pages; ); ?>' is printed on the page.

Comment: remove the semi-colon after `max_num_pages; ); ?> `    ->  `max_num_pages ); ?>`

Comment: It is still printing 'max_num_pages ); ?>' unfortunately :(

Comment: I literally pasted the php onto a wordpress page, and the javascript in the javascript footer. I have [products category="lingerie" paginate="true" limit="20" columns="4"] to display the products.